# How can I match Word Boundary "or" [@#]?

Tags: ruby, regex, word-boundary

I can't seem to get a regex that matches either a hashtag `#`, an `@`, or a word-boundary. The goal is to break a string into Twitter-like entities and topics so:

```
input = "Hello @world, #ruby anotherString" 
input.scan(entitiesRegex) 
# => ["Hello", "@world", "#ruby", "anotherString"]
```

To get just the words, excluding `"anotherString"` which is too large, is simple:

```
/\b\w{3,12}\b/
```

will return `["Hello", "world", "ruby"]`. Unfortunately this doesn't include the hashtags and `@`s. It seems like it should work simply with:

```
/[\b@#]\w{3,12}\b/
```

but that returns `["@world", "#ruby"]`. This made me realize that word boundaries are not by definition a character, so they don't fall into the category of "A single character" and, so, won't match. A few more attempts:

```
/\b|[@#]\w{3,12}\b/
```

returns `["", "", "@world", "", "#ruby", "", "", ""]`.

```
/((\b|[@#])\w{3,12}\b)/
```

matches the right things, but returns `[[""], ["@"], ["#"], [""]]` as expected, because the braces also mean capture everything enclosed.

```
/((\b|[@#])\w{3,12}\b)/
```

kind of works. It returns `[["Hello", ""], ["@world", "@"], ["#ruby", "#"]]`. So now all the correct items are there, they're just located at the first element of each of the subarrays. The following snippet technically works:

```
input.scan(/((\b|[@#])\w{3,12}\b)/).collect(&:first)
```

Is it possible to simplify this to match and return the correct substrings with just the regular expression not requiring the `collect` post-processing?

Comment: A [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` is a zero-width match. An anchor, matching a position.

Comment: Yes, but it appears that characters retrieved by the square-brackets "or" must have at least 1-width. So `[\b@#]` only matches "# or @", but `[\s@#]` will match "a white-space character, #, or @". Otherwise my second regex ought have worked.

Comment: Imho it makes no sense to put an [anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) into a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). But sure makes sense to put [shorthands](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) like `\s` into one :)

Comment: I agree fully with that :) . I'm not trying to point out a problem with how Ruby matches regex, I think that it's perfectly fine - I'm just trying to see if there's a way for me to simplify my code to only a regex match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the regular expression `/[@#]?\b\w+\b/`. That is, optionally match a `@` or `#`, followed by a word boundary (in `#ruby`, that boundary would be between `#` and `ruby`, in a normal word it would also match at the start of the word) and a bunch of word characters.

```
p "Hello @world, #ruby anotherString".scan(/[@#]?\b\w+\b/)
# => ["Hello", "@world", "#ruby", "anotherString"]
```

Furthermore, you can adjust the number of characters a matching word should have with quantifiers. You gave an example in a comment to a deleted answer to match only `#ruby` by using `{3,4}`:

```
p "Hello @world, #ruby anotherString".scan(/[@#]?\b\w{3,4}\b/)
# => ["#ruby"]
```

Comment: (If length is not concerned, which the OP is not entirely clear about), then `\b` is redundant. `\w+` will match whenever possible and as long as it can, so it will automatically match at word boundaries. However, the OP seems to have something with length, which makes it complicated.

Comment: Wow. Way too simple, I cannot believe I skipped that. Love it!

Comment: @sawa Yes you are right, but to handle the case of specific lengths I added it.